# Column static grouping in Matrix

Tags: reporting-services, grouping

I'm trying to create a technical indicator in Microsoft SSRS. I have a dataset that has a table that tells me whether or not my product has passed various stages in testing and I want to take one of those stages and break it into two sub columns statically. So for instance I have temperature and want to break it out into min and max operating temp so the columns will look like:

```
|   Weight   |   Height   |   Temperature  |   Length    |
                          |  min  |  max   |
```

However I can't find any way to statically define the column breakdowns for Temperature, and one of my main problems is I need to pull the min max data from a different database than the rest of the information and therefore need to make it it's own dataset. Do you have any ideas on what I could group on or how to get this to split up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring how to do this by creating a new row and then stretching the group over two columns. Then I just hid the unwanted columns with an if statement.